# Как правильно экспортировать/импортировать функцию React

Tags: reactjs, export, create-react-app

Пытаюсь написать собственный декоратор. Вот код декоратора :

```
const userAuth = observable({
 isAuth: true,
});

export const isAuth = () => {
 if (userAuth.isAuth) {
  return (
   <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
 );
}
 return (
  <Redirect to="/login" />
 );
};

export default { isAuth };
```

В другом файле я подключаю это следующим образом:

```
import { isAuth } from './routes/auth/authChecker';

@isAuth()
class App extends React.Component {
....
```

Мне выдает ошибку...

```
[dev:server] /home/dmitry/web/tennis-front/node- 
seed/tmp/bundle.js:50261
[2]     import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
[2]     ^^^^^^
[2] 
[2] SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис декораторов не поддерживается в `create-react-app` из коробки, поэтому нужно добавить [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy).

Детальнее читайте [здесь](https://medium.com/@jihdeh/es7-decorators-in-reactjs-22f701a678cd)